# Use of Casting on a parameter

Tags: java, iframe, casting, instanceof

IFrame it is an interface (That I should not modify) and Frame it is the extended class.

I need to use casting or instance of to reffer to use f as Frame instead os IFrame.

How can I achieve this?

```
public class Frame implements IFrame{
    private int numRows;
    private char code[][];
@Override
   public void replace(IFrame f) {
        for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
            for (int o=0; o<numRows; o++){

               (Frame f).code[i][o] = this.code[i][o];

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `(Frame f).code[i][o];`?

Comment: It still gives me an error from IDE

Comment: Well, you are just getting an element from the array but not doing anything with it. What error do you get?

Comment: the actual code is this(Frame f).code[i][o] = this.code[i][o];

I have this error 
Error:java: ';' expected
Error: java: not a statement

Comment: My bad, to cast you have to use `((Frame) f)`, not `(Frame f)`. Does this work?

Comment: It works great!! thanks Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((Frame) f).code[i][o] = this.code[i][o]` should work but I suggest you test if the passed parameter actually is an instance of `Frame` before copying to avoid casting errors. Also, you should make sure that `numRows` of the passed `Frame` is greater or equal than the one of the called instance:

```
public void replace(IFrame iFrame) {
    if (iFrame instanceof Frame) {
        Frame f = (Frame) iFrame;
        if (f.numRows < this.numRows) {
            // Do what you want to do if the provided frame has fewer rows than this frame
            return; // Return in the if condition, this way you do not proceed to the for loop causing an IndexOutOfBounds exception
        }
        for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++){
            for (int o=0; o<numRows; o++){
                   (Frame f).code[i][o] = this.code[i][o];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need another set of parantheses for the cast:

```
public void replace(IFrame f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
        for (int o = 0; o < numRows; o++) {
            ((Frame) f).code[i][o] = this.code[i][o];
        }
    }
}
```

It is also advisable to verify the runtime type of the parameter in the very first statement of the method, and react appropriately, e.g.:

```
    if (!(f instanceof Frame))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need an instance of Frame. Got an instance of " + f.getClass().getName() + ".");
```

A performance optimized verison of the array copying can be achieved by using *System.arraycopy*:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
    System.arraycopy(this.code[i], 0, ((Frame) f).code[i], 0, numRows);
}
```